# Referencing opinions that are visible in Google search results?

Tags: citations

I have this problem that I write:

"Image segmentation methods include region growing, region modelling and mathematical morphology"

These I can discover to exist in papers on image segmenting by doing a Google search. But I find it difficult to find a source that I could cite as for a "definition of image segmentation". And I'm not sure if this is even necessary. And if I would reference, say three papers just in order to prove that these are image segmentation methods, then it would seem overkill.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't "define" image segmentation, but I know it when I see it. This seems a bit odd, actually.

Answer (score 1):

In my field, it is common to see this type of thing in the "related work" section of a paper. And it is almost always accompanied by citations. What is "overkill" and why are you afraid of it? Citations don't clutter a paper *that* much that you have to be afraid of including them.

Think of it this way, if a entry-level graduate student was reading your paper, and didn't know exactly what region modelling meant, it would be helpful to have a single paper to go to that provides a description. Especially if there is any ambiguity among terms, you can clear up what *you* mean by "region modelling" by simply including a reference.

Comment: It's overkill if it can be considered "basic knowledge" to know or be able to seek what image segmentation methods for example exist. If the paper is about image segmentation methods at other than elementary level.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for a review paper to cite, a Google Scholar search for:

> "image segmentation" review

shows a lot of promising possibilities (and you can probably get more specific results if you also include the specific techniques you are mentioning), and gives a reader novice to the field an entry point to finding other literature on the techniques you mention.